# How to cast object to method return type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, casting, postsharp

I want to set `args.ReturnValue` to instance of an object created from `TResponse<T>` method called `Create`.

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class LogError : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Logging part..

        MethodInfo methodInfo = (MethodInfo)args.Method;

        // I want to replace line below comment to get TResponse<T> object instead of dynamic if possible
        dynamic returnValue = Activator.CreateInstance(methodInfo.ReturnType);
        args.ReturnValue = returnValue.Create(CodeMessage.InternalError, MessageType.Error, args.Exception);

        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    }
}
```

Method `ReturnType` will always be `TResponse<T>`, but I don't know how to create instance of `TResponse<T>` based on method return type. `TResponse<T>` implements method with this signature:

```
.Create(CodeMessage.InternalError, MessageType.Error, args.Exception);
```

`Create` method is static method that returns `TResponse<T>` object with parameters set.

Since I didn't know how to do what I want I used `Activator` to create instance of method return type and store it to `dynamic` type, but it throws `RuntimeBinderException` when I call `Create` method.

Comment: Have you tried `methodInfo.ReturnType.GetConstructor(...).Invoke(...)`?

Comment: @BastiM Thanks, your comment helped me out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Create(...)` is static, you don't need to create an instance by using the `Activator` class. Just get a `MethodInfo` from the ReturnType and invoke it with `null` as first argument:

```
public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    // Logging part..

    MethodInfo methodInfo = (MethodInfo)args.Method;

    MethodInfo create = methodInfo.ReturnType.GetMethod(
                    "Create",
                    new[] { typeof(CodeMessage), typeof(MessageType), typeof(Exception) });
    args.ReturnValue = create.Invoke(null, new object[] { CodeMessage.InternalError, MessageType.Error, args.Exception });

    args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
}
```

`MethodInfo.Invoke` returns an `object`. Since `MethodExecutionArgs.ReturnValue` is also only an `object`, you don't need to cast to the actual `TResponse` type.

Anyway, if you need to set some additional properties on the return value, I would introduce a non-generic interface for `TResponse<T>`. You could then cast the result value to this interface and set the properties.

Comment: I figured it out myself based on Basti M comment. Thanks for your time, this is exactly what I did :)

Comment: Since it's a static method, I think you can not have a generic interface. No ?

Comment: @V.Couvignou: `Create(...)` can obviously not be part of the interface, but imagine a property like `string AdditionalErrorInfo { get; set; }`